# SQL Server Deadlock solving

Tags: java, sql-server, performance, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I'm facing an issue regarding deadlocks in my SQL Server database and I want to know how to get started to find the solution.

I first started facing deadlocks while running a JMeter script which simulated 10 concurrent users. I ran a trace in the SQL profiler and I noticed the two queries that were involved in the deadlock were the same SELECT query. I quickly solved this by adding the NOLOCK hint to them.

After this, another deadlock occured and I dirty fixed them by making a method synchronized in my Java application. Then another deadlock occured and I figured that this was not the way to work myself around this challenge.

Interesting and comforting is that the deadlocks all occur on the same table. This table is the core table of my applications and all the deadlocks are related to one of the 5 indexes on the table.

I am not experienced enough to know how to pinpoint the problem, leave aside the solution.
Is there anybody who can tell me how to approach this situation?

Thank you

Comment: The most common causes of frequent deadlocks are 1) suboptimal execution plans that cause more data than needed to be touched and 2) inconsistent data access order (one thread updates row1 then row2 and another row2 then row1).  I suggest you start with index and query tuning.  Consider changing the database to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT isolation rather than use the NOLOCK hint.

Answer (score 0):

These can be very difficult to isolate root cause (as you know).  As a DBA its very difficult to resolve in isolation as the queries are out of context.  The most success I have seen in this area, is having the developers and DBA next to each other and translating between each other what given queries are doing as deadlocks occur.  Your approach of using Profiler is correct, you just need that extra context from an application point of view and then you should start to see why you are getting the issue on the SQL Server.  (this assumes you are not the dev and DBA).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a DB transaction running on your table in any stored procedure or through your application that locks the table, to find that out run the below query to see if there is any active transaction that is taking too long and is stuck

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions where database_id = ??
```

You can find database ID from

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

Use the below query to check live deadlocks

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE blocked >0
```

Some other queries that can help you to resolve database issue are

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_current_transaction
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
SELECT * FROM sysobjects
```

Comment: I will try to use these statements to locate my deadlocks. Thanks @Paali.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on MS SQL Server but can tell you general pointers to look at,

Basically deadlocks happen because of locking. if you find solution for locking/unlocking your problem is resolved.

1. Try to optimize the queries which are participating in locks.

Many times single query runs for long duration acquiring locks and not finishing work in time, thus other queries wait for its completion which in turn results in deadlock. so try to otpimize the query first, see are you fetching the required data? if you are fetching unnecessary data then remove it. generally reading locks the rows and if your locklist (Max. No. of locks available to DB) is low then whole table gets locked which will cause deadlock.

1. If you are only reading data then use NOLOCK (which you have done already), instead of processing it in DB if logic is complex then process it in application
2. Check DB tunings,stats. are they in place?
   if not correct them and check again
3. If all above things did not work then finally go for difficult cases like splitting table horizontally,vertically which needs application knowledge and code modification.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to optimize my queries and post the results when I have them.